# Tizen Studio: Unable to install application due to signature error in certificate profile (Error: -12)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I am currently attempting to download an app onto a Samsung smartwatch (Galaxy Watch Active 2019, Tizen v4.0.0.3). I have been following the guide on creating a Native Tizen application and have followed everything step-by-step and can't get Tizen Studio to install the app due to a certificate error. This only seems to occur on an actual smartwatch, as I am perfectly able to install the app on the emulator.

I have already installed the Samsung Certificate Extension SDK in the Package Manager. I've already deleted all existing certificates and created new Samsung certificates to install on the smartwatch, but keep running into the same error. I have also uninstalled Tizen Studio and all files associated with it, as well as reset the Smartwatch.

This is the error message that the IDE puts out:

"error : -12
error message: :Device is not registered. Register this device first:<-30> 
end process (fail)
processing result : Check certificate error [-12] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [1430]ms
cmd_ret:244"

Answer (score 6):

Check how number of signature will be installed on your device:

open a command shell and execute the following:

==> sdb dlog | grep signature

[image: sdb dlog]

Try to install the app again via tizen studio and debug it. Look on the command shell for the number of signature files. If you have more than one, then you must delete all certificates and restart the step-by-step certification creating workflow again.

In step 4 ==> Add individual DUIDs
fill only one DUID and remove the entry from the local image device

[image: certification manager step 4]
That it's
Tested: Tizen Studio 3.2; Galaxy Watch 4; Tizen V4.0.0.4

Comment: Or simply make sure that the emulator is **not** running during certificate generation!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your date and time on the watch are right.
Thing that you described happen to me when my "timezone" on the watch wasn't correct. That happen because the watch was not paired with a phone (standalone mode) and had "KST" timezone on it (default one).

Answer (score 0):

Late but might help, see the time and date match in both the device and computer. DUID may not be properly registered for that device you are trying to test.

Comment: why do you need a DUID to be registered if you are downloading from store? he says he is downloading. DUIDs only needed for installing using Tizen Stuido i think